# Time series analysis in Python using conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I have the following data (sample)

```
Symbol Sections      iBid     Bid                Date
0    O.U20       O1  99.73167  99.730 2020-06-29 16:32:25
1    O.Z20       O1  99.70250  99.700 2020-06-29 16:32:25
2    O.H21       O1       NaN  99.795 2020-06-29 16:32:25
3    O.M21       O1  99.81167  99.810 2020-06-29 16:32:25
4    O.U21       O2  99.81667  99.815 2020-06-29 16:32:25
5    O.Z21       O2       NaN  99.795 2020-06-29 16:32:25
6    O.H22       O2  99.81000  99.810 2020-06-29 16:32:25
7    O.M22       O2  99.79500  99.795 2020-06-29 16:32:25
16  F3.U26       F3       NaN   1.000 2020-06-29 16:32:25
17  F3.Z26       F3       NaN  -3.000 2020-06-29 16:32:25
18  F3.H27       F3       NaN  -1.000 2020-06-29 16:32:25
19  F6.H26       F6  -1.75000     NaN 2020-06-29 16:32:25
20  F6.M26       F6  -4.50000     NaN 2020-06-29 16:32:25
21  F6.U26       F6  -5.50000     NaN 2020-06-29 16:32:25
22  F9.U20       F9  -8.50000  -9.000 2020-06-29 16:32:25
23   O.U20       O3  99.73167  99.730 2020-06-29 16:32:26
24   O.Z20       O3  99.70250  99.700 2020-06-29 16:32:26
25   O.H21       O3       NaN  99.795 2020-06-29 16:32:26
26   O.M21       O3  99.81167  99.810 2020-06-29 16:32:26
27   O.U21       O4  99.81667  99.815 2020-06-29 16:32:26
28   O.Z21       O4       NaN  99.795 2020-06-29 16:32:26
29   O.H22       O4  99.81000  99.810 2020-06-29 16:32:26
30   O.M22       O4  99.79500  99.795 2020-06-29 16:32:26
```

What I want to do is draw a scatterplot or a line chart or any kind of chart that is suitable for such an analysis that can analyze the trend over time if a condition is met. For example, I want to see how many times iBid is higher than Bid overtime for each symbol like (O,S,F) and also for sections (O1,F3 etc)

I know I'm required to present some working but I'm not sure if such a chart is even possible? So far I can only do is sperate the data based on Symbol

```
df_O = df[df['Contract'].str.contains('O')]
```

and filter out the results like

```
IbidgreaterBid = big_frame[(big_frame.iBid > big_frame.Bid)]
```

Is it possible to obtain a graph that can analyze when is Ibid > Bid with Date column as x axis? (Date column has thousand of rows with the only difference of seconds)

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you mean by a graph that can analyze when ibid > bid. However, I can suggest a way to distinguish data based on Ibid >/< Bid. In the following example, red scatter points indicate data points where Ibid > Bid, blue for otherwise. Moreover, because the difference is only on the second's scale, I've made use of `mdates` date-formatter to set xticks to show H-M-S only.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.offsetbox import AnchoredText
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from datetime import timedelta
plt.style.use('seaborn-whitegrid')

n_sections=df['Sections'].nunique()
cols=2
rows=int(round(n_sections/2.0))
#setup the plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(rows, cols, figsize=(16,8),sharex=False,sharey=False) # if you want to turn off sharing axis.
row=0 #to iterate over rows/cols
col=0 #to iterate over rows/cols


for index, Section in df.groupby('Sections'):
    ax[row][col].scatter(np.array(Section['Datetime']),Section['iBid'] , color='blue')
    ax[row][col].scatter(np.array(Section['Datetime'][Section['iBid']>Section['Bid']]),Section['iBid'][Section['iBid']>Section['Bid']] , color='red')
    ax[row][col].set_xlim([min(Section['Datetime'])-timedelta(seconds=5), max(Section['Datetime'])+timedelta(seconds=5)])
    ax[row][col].set_xlabel('Date Time',fontsize=20)
    ax[row][col].set_ylabel('iBid',fontsize=20)
    anchored_text = AnchoredText("{}".format(Section['Sections'].unique()[0]), loc=4,prop=dict(size=20))
    ax[row][col].add_artist(anchored_text)

    ax[row][col].xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S'))
    ax[row][col].tick_params(axis='both', direction='in', which='major', length=5, width=2,labelsize=16)
    
    row=row+1
    if row==rows:
        row=0
        col=col+1
```

[image]